# i want show alert with page url

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to show alert message when user failed to login with url value .

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
   var retVal = confirm("Login FAILED! Do you want to continue ?");
   if( retVal == true ){
      window.location.href = "login.php";
      return true;
   }else{
      alert("User does not want to continue!");
      return false;
   }
//-->
</script>
```

this is url value

```
/?redirect_to=%2Fstarstruckmedia%2F%3Flogin%3Dfailed%26redirect_to%3D%252Fstarstruckmedia%252F&login=failed
```

Comment: You can't use `return` unless you are in a function.

Comment: Then what i can do@  you have any idea how  show alert with page value

Comment: Start with opening your console. It says : `Uncaught SyntaxError: Illegal return statement`. As @Scott says, remove the `return` stuff. Sidenote : I like "illegal" stuff in a browser console, always feels like you're going to jail or something

Comment: Just remove those lines. See my working answer below.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `return` unless you are in a function. Take those lines out and your code works.

```js
var retVal = confirm("Login FAILED! Do you want to continue ?");
if(retVal){
   window.location.href = "login.php";
} else {
   alert("User does not want to continue!\n" + window.location.href);
}
```

Comment: `==true` also redundant

Comment: Scott Marcus@window.location.href = "login.php";  I want  alert with this url value

Comment: @sanjayyadav What do you mean? If the user does not want to continue, you still want to show the login URL? You can modify the `alert()` to show whatever you want. That wasn't your question. You can see that this code now does display the `alert`.

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain the url of the current page using `window.location.href`. See [this](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp) for details.

```js
   var retVal = confirm("Login FAILED! Do you want to continue ?");
   if( retVal == true ){
      window.location.href = "login.php";
   }else{
      alert(window.location.href);
   }
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged. Please add an explanation.